# Gridview limits the child's content

Tags: gridview, flutter, dart

I got this `GridView` that doesn't fit the GridTile's child content entirely. See [image](https://ibb.co/VjSbD8F).

The only way not to get a rendering error is to apply the `shrinkWrap` property to the GridView, which I don't want since the `EmployeeCard` is not a ListView that gets scrolled, it's a column. Is there any way to fix this ?

```
GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: hardcodedEmployee.map((employeeName){
    return GridTile(
      child: EmployeeCard(name: employeeName),
    );
  }).toList()
)
```

Comment: Check out the Expanded class - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: @newbie99 Can you please add the code for `EmployeeCard`, so that we know the widgets it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways for achieving what you desribed:

1. You can set `childAspectRatio` to something like 0.9 in `GridView.count` contstructor.
2. You can try using other GridView constructors, but it will require you to provide custom gridDelegate for grid view
3. Try using [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) library, which allows grid cells to wrap it contents